# Why does changing quarter to months of time series change the R-squared value?

Tags: regression, time-series, linear, r-squared

When I use plot the average value month on month Vs quarter on quarter, I get different R-squared value.
What does this mean for my regression? Do I pick month / quarter based on a higher R-squared value?

Comment: What is best to do depends (also) on your *purpose*, not on R-squared ... (you forgot to tell us)

Comment: Read about the [ecological fallacy](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=%22ecological+fallacy%22).  There are some good posts here on CV: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=ecological+fallacy.

Comment: Sorry, specifically which subset of the ecological fallacy are you thinking of? 
My purpose is to gauge the number of transactions in real estate market throughout the business year.

Answer (score 0):

R-squared value depends on the number of data.
when you use the quarterly plot of original values, the data is already clustered quarterly and in each quarter some averaging is already in-place. In other words, in each quarter which is represented by only one value, you already made those data averaged into one value and the add all those quarterly-averaged values into new plot.